# Tensorflow : Transform class name to class index

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, mapping

I am working on machine learning stuff with tensorflow.

**Problem :**

I can't fingure out how to transform class name into class index.

**Example :**

Expected mapping :

```
Car  ---> 0
Bike ---> 1
Boat ---> 2
```

Code :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import tensorflow as tf

names = [
    "Car",
    "Bus",
    "Boat"
]

_, class_name = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1).read(
    tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.gfile.Glob("input_file.csv"))
)

# I want to know if it is possible to do that :
#    print(sess.run(class_name)) --> "Car"
#    class_index = f(class_name, names)
#    print(sess.run(class_index)) --> 0
```

input_file.csv :

```
class_name
Car
Car
Boat
Bike
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is this:

```py
class_index = tf.reduce_min(tf.where(tf.equal(names, class_name)))
```

Note that it works fine, while the class is present in `names`, but returns 2<sup>63</sup> − 1, when it is not (like `Bike` in your example). You can avoid this effect but removing `tf.reduce_min`, but in this case `class_index` will evaluate to an array, not scalar.

Complete runnable code:

```py
names = ["Car", "Bus", "Boat"]

_, class_name = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1).read(
    tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.gfile.Glob("input_file.csv"))
)
class_index = tf.reduce_min(tf.where(tf.equal(names, class_name)))

with tf.Session() as session:
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(4):
    print(class_name.eval())  # Car, Car, Boat, Bike
  for i in range(4):
    print(class_index.eval()) # 0, 0, 2, 9223372036854775807

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Thank you some much ! You can't imagine how many time that I have passed to search for this line of code !